# Laravel - Create Separate Row for Data from txt file for mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am having an problem with this. Say, for example I these lines of data:

```
QZS-2 (QZSS/PRN 184)    
1 42738U 17028A   17258.40853294 -.00000184  00000-0  00000-0 0  9994
2 42738  44.6467 288.3531 0740253 270.7360  80.8515  1.00267707  1090
```

These lines give some details about an orbit of an satellite. Line 0 is the name while lines 1 and 2 are orbital parameters.

So far I have managed to save these lines to the mySQL database using this:

```
public function displayer() {
    $url = 'http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/sbas.txt';
    $lines = file($url, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $arrays = array_map(function($array) {
        $columns = ['object_name', 'tle_line1', 'tle_line2'];
        return array_combine($columns, array_map('trim', $array));
    }, array_chunk($lines, 3));
    DB::table('tester')->insert($arrays);
    dd($arrays);
}
```

This works great and manages to create the 3 lines I need. Now for the problem I am trying to solve:

I am trying to create a separate row for the five digit number (also called the `norad_cat_id`). So for example:

`2 42738  44.6467 288.3531 0740253 270.7360  80.8515  1.00267707  1090`  creates a row with the number `42738`. So each satellite should have 4 columns of data each: the three lines already present and now the new `norad_cat_id` five digit number. The data follows a standard: the line where the `norad_cat_id` is present always has a `2` at the start of it and a then a space.

Sometimes the `norad_cat_id` can have a zero at the start of number: for example: `08513`. Would it be possible just to save `8513` to the database without the zero?

**TL;DR**

- Add/create separate row for `norad_cat_id`.
- Remove zero if the `norad_cat_id` starts with zero.

**EDIT:**
Maybe something can be done with this (I found this on an another answer):

```
$splitName = explode(' ', $name, 2); 
$first_name = $splitName[0];
$last_name = !empty($splitName[1]) ? $splitName[1] : '';
```

This splits first and last names. Maybe something can be derived from this?

Comment: i think if `norad_cat_id` column is integer in the database table it will rip it off the zero. Else if you want to preserve the zero, one of the best way is to have the column as char or string related. Does this seem that I understood you correctly?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi - You are correct, I do not need the zero.

Comment: so make the `norad_cat_id` as integer field in the database then...

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi - I guess I could do that. But that only solves have half of the question. I need to add a separate row for `norad_cat_id`.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi Just tested your solution and can confirm it works! Thanks! Only thing left is the split the data as in the question.

Comment: Is it a separate row in another table or a column in the same row?

Comment: @TheAlpha A column in the same row.

Comment: So, there will be total four columns as `'object_name', 'tle_line1', 'tle_line2', 'norad_cat_id'`, right?

Comment: @TheAlpha That is correct.

Comment: @D.777KLM, check the updated answer, it's more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your modified code which will create each row using four columns:

```
public function displayer()
{
    $url = 'http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/sbas.txt';
    $lines = file($url, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $arrays = array_map(function($array) {
        $columns = ['object_name', 'tle_line1', 'tle_line2'];
        $row = array_combine($columns, array_map('trim', $array));

        // New line added
        return array_merge($row, [
            'norad_cat_id' => (int) explode(' ', end($row), 3)[1]
        ]);

    }, array_chunk($lines, 3));

    DB::table('tester')->insert($arrays);
}
```